# Flask application - connection refused without any error

Tags: python, flask, localhost

Currently I'm working on flask app. Its main task is to retrieve data from .ifc file (filesize is about 20-30mb) with numpy and pandas, generate dataframe and save it as csv file in directory for later usage. Each file is stored in directory and its informations are stored in database:

```
class IfcFile(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    filepath = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    filesize = db.Column(db.Float)
    plates_1D_file = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    plates_2D_file = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'IfcFile: ({self.id}) {self.filename}'
```

Button's 'a' tag related to the function is like:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('generate_all', file_id=file.id) }}"
```

and the function:

```
@app.route('/generate/<file_id>')
def generate_all(file_id):

    file_db = IfcFile.query.filter_by(id=file_id).first()
    plates_1D_df, plates_2D_df = generate_df_plates(file_db.filepath)

    # till now everything's fine

    plates_1D_df.to_csv(config.UPLOAD_1D_PLATES_FOLDER)
    plates_2D_df.to_csv(config.UPLOAD_1D_PLATES_FOLDER)
    
    print('Saved files')
    
    file_db.plates_1D_file = config.UPLOAD_1D_PLATES_FOLDER
    file_db.plates_1D_file = config.UPLOAD_1D_PLATES_FOLDER

    return redirect(url_for('files_db'))
```

generate_df_plates - function stored in another file, correct, no need to place it here

So the thing is when I press that button calling above function dataframes are generated (I know it because I printed it to cmd) but when I'm trying to save as csv file or even print dataframes to cmd - flask app immediately stops withour any error and in my webbrowser I have window saying

'The site can't be reached
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'.

I develop my app on 127.0.0.1, localhost.
I guess that it can be related to time of execution because when I was running the code with jupyter notebook which generates dataframes i took about 20-30 secs to run. Can you guys help me overcome this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your url before and after clicking on that button and also put a ```print``` in this ```generate_all``` view to check if you reach this function or not . Then report back

Comment: Thanks for help. I searched for bugs every file in my app and finally I found one in the another imported file.